# How write a Django REST APIView POST request with a condition?

Tags: api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a post request for a game api. The game implies that a user can label a picture. A label entered once is a tagging, a label entered twice for the same resource is a tag.
This is how I am trying to create a Tagging so far:

```
saved_tagging = Tagging.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                               gameround=gameround,
                                               resource=random_resource,
                                               tag='tag newwww',
                                               created=datetime.now(),
                                               score=score,
                                               origin=origin
                                               )
        tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(saved_tagging)
```

At the moment I am getting the ValueError: `Cannot assign "'tag newwww'": "Tagging.tag" must be a "Tag" instance.`

Is there any way that I can avoid this?

Here are also my models and the relevant serializer.

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
        return tag_data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''


class Tagging(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tagging')
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        tagging = Tagging.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Tag.objects.create(name=tagging, **tag_data)
        return tagging

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag) or ''
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TaggingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tag = StringRelatedField()
  resource = ResourceSerializer(read_only=True)
  gameround = GameroundSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Tagging
    fields = ('id', 'tag', 'gameround', 'created', 'score', 'resource', 'origin')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    return Tagging.objects.create(**validated_data)

  def to_representation(self, data):
    data = super().to_representation(data)
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

tag must be a Tag Instance !
So... you can do this in two ways (in my opinion).
First you can create a Tag object in your view and than pass this object to tag value in your Tagging create method.

Or create a service layer on your app, and create a custom create method for your model. This in my opinion is superior because your a centralizing your rules in one method instead of in one view.

Ex.:
services/tag_service.py

```py
def create(user_id,gameround,resource,tag,...origin):
    if not isinstance(tag, Tag):
        #create your tag model based on the String passed
        your_new_tag_object = Tag.objects.create(tag=tag, ...)

    
    # Here your create others rules too for model creation
    # Return your model .create method
    return Tagging.objects.create(user_id=user_id,...tag=your_new_tag_object,...)
```

And Than use this new create method inside your POST serializer.

```py
from services import tag_service

class TaggingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  # your normal serializer here

  def create(self, validated_data):
    return tag_service.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Well, I have tried the first one so far and it doesn't work so well since I have to delete the Tag if it doesn't exist as a Tagging. I'll try the services solution. Does it make a difference where I add the tag_service.py file? can I add it to the same directory as my views.py file?

Comment: I believe for practical reasons, will be no problems to put this services into the views file. But for project organization will make a mess hehe.
A services.py file or a services/your_model_services.py will make a cleaner.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! And the create() method is basically the logic behind when to save a Tag or Tagging instance, right? This is where I put the condition, right?

Comment: Yes, the main deal about this services layer is to put your business logic behind it.